# Is there a javascript MVVM framework like KnockoutJS that works with Adobe Air?

Tags: javascript, air

I have an HTML/Javascript application that is written using [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/). I really enjoyed working with Knockout. It was EXACTLY what I was looking for. But, now, when I try to create an Adobe Air application with my Knockout app, the build fails with security sandbox errors. I found out later that the sandbox doesn't allow some javascript commands that Knockout uses (namely `eval`). So... now, I'm looking for something similar to Knockout that doesn't violate the [HTML security policies of Adobe Air](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/security/WS485a42d56cd196415cc29732124ef23decb-7ff5.html). Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search through my source code doesn't turn up any use of 'eval' in Backbone.js.

I don't see a mention of 'new' not being allowed on the air docs.

Comment: It is very different from Knockout. I may go with backbone, but I'm hoping for something more similar to Knockout so I won't have to re-write so much of the app.